# Writing data to OutputStream from Native Code

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a JNI method like this

```
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_lib_Fs_readFile
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring java_string, jobject stream) {
  unsigned char read_block[1024] = { 0 };

 }
```

How can I write read_block[1024] to

```
jobject stream
```

that is OutputStream from native code?

Comment: I wouldn't even try.  Return the block of 1024 bytes to the Java code, and let Java write the bytes.

Comment: This in not an option! I REALLY need to use OutputStream there.